# Connection to <IP-ADDRESS> closed

Tags: ssh

When I try and ssh into my Digital Ocean [droplet](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/droplets/overview/)<sup>1</sup> I see this:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-127-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
    http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud

21 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.


*** System restart required ***
Last login: Thu Jul 12 15:03:22 2018 from 90.xxx.xxx.119
Connection to 178.xxx.xxx.168 closed.
```

*(I've obscured the IP addresses with `x`s)*

So ssh is connecting, but immediately being "kicked out".

Short of a hard reset of the server (which seems a bit OTT), what can I do?

#### Update

I tried running `ssh` in ultra-verbose debug level 3 mode (`ssh -vvv ...`). I've pasted the output [here](https://pastebin.com/LusYCfcM), although I can't see anything particularly interesting there.

I've also tried hard-resetting my server and, when it comes back up, I have the same problem!

#### Update

I can boot the server from a recovery ISO, but I'm not sure what to do once I'm there!

---

<sup>1</sup> A droplet is just an Ubuntu VM running on Digital Ocean's servers.

Comment: I could imagine that your ssh user's login shell is either wrong or that it's auto-running something which crashes or closes it immediately. Can you try if you can connect with `ssh YOUR_SERVER sh -il`?

Comment: When I run `ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx sh -il` I get the same as in the original post, but without the last two lines. So the output ends with `*** System restart required ***`. Same if I try any other command. The commands given to `ssh` are unquoted right?

Comment: can you run a single command `ssh -t <user@host> "echo test"`?

Comment: @rtaft Thanks for the suggestion. But nothing changes. `test` doesn't get echoed.

Comment: Did you try it with some other user than root?

Comment: @muclux I don't *have* any other users yet! 

Comment: How about `ssh -t user@host /bin/bash`? Or else bash with `--noprofile` and/or `--norc`?